# Using sqlite3 in iOS Projects

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

This is how I currently have my methods in my project to use sqlite queries to return `NSObject`s to be used in my iOS project:

[image: sqlite3 preview]

- in the launch of my application, each table is checked if it needs to be created
- in the application, there is no `DROP TABLE ..` queries nor `ALTER TABLE ..`

My question is:

1. should I be checking if a table exists every time I'm going to create a sqlite3 query?
2. should i use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ..` vs checking if a table exists using a different query like:

   `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type IN ('table','view') AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%' UNION ALL SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master WHERE type IN ('table','view') ORDER BY 1;`and iterating the names of the tables and checking if the table name exists?

I want to create the least amount of overhead. i am not using Core Data as well

Also, while updating records, i've noticed if i insert the name of a column, it takes the value of that column:

[image: sql preview]

Comment: 1. If your intention is to create a table using sqlite3 Query - CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS - you may do this.
2. If you are intended in other operations like fetching data from Sqlite DB you don't have to check for table existence.

Comment: so just running CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS every time the application launches is insuring enough?

Comment: Yes, as per your design I see, you are creating table if not found in AppDelegate. Enough.